# Calibrate touchscreen and onscreen keyboard with Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: touchscreen

I have an HP Spectre Folio 13 with a touchscreen, and just installed Ubuntu 19.04. 
All hardware works, and with some fiddling I also got Firefox to work with touchscreen scrolling and figured out basic gnome gestures. 
But the touchscreen could use some calibration. 
I can't figure out how? Most search results are really old. 
Seems like there's a difference between configuring with Wayland and Xorg? I guess 19.04 uses Wayland instead of Xorg (not sure exactly what that means)?

So how do I calibrate the touchscreen? I want it to a tad more sensitive.

Also the onscreen keyboard in Gnome is not that good. It doesn't have support for international letters (I'm Norwegian, so I need those) and quite slow.
The good thing is that it pops up when I need it. Is there a way to configure the onscreen keyboard and add international letters? And make it a bit faster so I can type normally.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same laptop.

I tried doing things in Wayland and it hasn't been very pleasant. You should switch to Xorg.

For calibration: it depends on what you mean. What exactly do you want to do? see if you can use xsetwacom. There is a lot of [documentation](https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/xsetwacom).

As you can see in this link, you can edit things like the transformation matrix, which will allow you to correct the offset of your pen if it is not correct as well as the pressure sensitivity curve and many other settings for your touchscreen/active stylus.

IMO Onboard keyboard works better than the one Ubuntu uses by default. You should look into that.